# What happened to the jockey-gtk command?

Tags: apt, command-line

I installed the [jockey-gtk [image: Install jockey-gtk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jockey-gtk) package using the following command:

```
nathan@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jockey-gtk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 176 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,228 B/3,228 B of archives.
After this operation, 53.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package jockey-gtk.
(Reading database ... 153816 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking jockey-gtk (from .../jockey-gtk_0.9.7-0ubuntu13_all.deb) ...
Setting up jockey-gtk (0.9.7-0ubuntu13) ...
```

But when I attempt to actually run the command:

```
nathan@ubuntu:~$ jockey-gtk
The program 'jockey-gtk' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk
```

Why am I receiving this error message? *I just installed the package!*

This machine is running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit - which I installed only yesterday.